# Qt 5 put Qt5Core.dll in a folder

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5, qtcore

Now I have such structure of my app files:

```
-myApp.exe
-Qt5Core.dll
-Qt5Gui.dll
-Qt5Widgets.dll
-platforms
|-qwindows.dll
```

Is it possible to put all dlls into one folder:

```
-myApp.exe
-libs
|-Qt5Core.dll
|-Qt5Gui.dll
|-Qt5Widgets.dll
|-platforms
||-qwindows.dll
```

I know I can build Qt statically and run apps without any dlls at all but I want to keep them, just put into one folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to put all dlls into one folder:

Yes, sure. You need to set up the dedicated folder properly so that the application can find the libraries. You can add that folder to the PATH for instance.

Basically, as per [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), this is the order how Windows tries to locate a `DLL`:

> - The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
> - The current directory.
> - The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> - The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> - The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Will it work if it loads libraries manually in the `main` function?

Comment: @johny: in that case, you can use QLibrary and co in a Qt application to be cross-platform.